# Pass parent of an item into a partial with Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template like this:

```
{{#each items}}
  <li id="{{id}}"><a href="#{{../route}}/{{id}}">{{name}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Now I want to split this template as I want to reuse the template for `li`

**main.hbs:**

```
{{#each items}}
  {{>child }}
{{/each}}
```

**child.hbs**

```
<li id="{{id}}"><a href="#{{../route}}/{{id}}">{{name}}</a></li>
```

But unfortunattly the child template cant access `../route`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the parent context to the child partial like so:

```
{{#each items}}
  {{>child this}}
{{/each}}
```

You are also going to probably fix the route value to look like this

```
<li id="{{id}}"><a href="../{{route}}/{{id}}">{{name}}</a></li>
```